# Should every MYSQL field, that would be used in a "WHERE" clause- have an index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering whether indexes should be added to various fields in a table, when it's known that those fields would be used in "SELECT...WHERE [field] = ..." queries.

For example, let's say i have a "user" table with the following fields:

```
 id(primary), userName, firstName, lastName
```

Assuming i will have a query like "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userName = 'someUser123';", should an index be added to the `userName` column?

Will this query be faster if an index is present, in a scenario where i have thousands of records?

Comment: [This can be useful](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229064/which-columns-should-be-indexed-when-all-may-be-used-in-different-search-queries)

Comment: Sorry I misread your title, I thought you wanted to index every column regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, searching a column is faster if there's an index.

Think of a telephone book. If I ask you to look up everyone whose last name is "Smith" it's very quick because you can assume the book is sorted by last name, and all the "Smiths" are together, and alphabetized.

That's the basic idea of how indexes work. They're sorted, and because of this, a search can be done a lot quicker.

Should you index *every* column? That's a much more complex question.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

And the video of me presenting it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: 'a telephone book' ? haven't seen one of those in years

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I saw also that you've written a book on SQL :D

Comment: @P.Salmon, Ha ha, but nevertheless they still exist.